# how to access a UINavigationController(created in storyboard) in AppDelegate.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, xcode-storyboard

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
AllListsViewController *controller = navigationController.viewControllers[0];
controller.dataModel = _dataModel;
```

This is my former code. I can access the AllListsViewController through navigationController since it's the rootViewController.

But now my storyboard changed. I've tried to access the controller the same way, but it wouldn't work.

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = (SWRevealViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)revealViewController.frontViewController;
AllListsViewController *controller = navigationController.viewControllers[0];

controller.dataModel = _dataModel;
```

Maybe it's because I set the frontViewController in storyboard so this revealViewController.frontViewController is nil. But I don't know other ways to access it from AppDelegate.m.

Sorry I can't post any images because of my reputation. Here's my code.https://github.com/liukaiyi54/CheckList

Somebody help me please. I've been tortured by this for days.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use storyboard ID and call your view controller based on storyboard ID

Comment: @Mr.T Works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//This is Main unless you have named your storyboard something different
  UIStoryboard *storyBoard =[ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  //make sure to put this in "AllListsViewController" in your identifier in the storyboard
  UINavigationController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AllListsViewController"];
  UINavigationController *myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
  self.window.rootViewController = myNavigationController;
```

This is where you would put your storyboard ID in the blue box:

[image]

Comment: I tried it and it still wouldn't. The method instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: creates a new controller, I think. I don't want a new one since I already created one in my storyboard and I can't set the rootViewController again since I already have a rootViewController in the storyboard. Not sure if I understand it correctly.  All I wanted to do is to save the data to iPhone. I can do it without adding the SWRevealViewController, but I really got myself lost in it now.  Maybe you can see my code if you got the time. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? AppDelegate is usually for telling your application to go to a view on launch or when a token is received etc.

Comment: I only wanted to save the data. I did it fine before add the SWRevealViewController. And now I'm completely lost.

Comment: It worked, though still got a little problem but I think I'll try to handle it. Thank you for your answer. You're really nice!!